# Unity3D Particle Playground 3.0.3 AddNode issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

I use Particle Playground 3.0.3 in Unity3d 5.4.1f1 on Windows 10 to make spline of particles. I need to add and remove node interactively. When I try do this through script — nodes add and remove but particles stop to move after 1-2 (rarely more) iterations.

The code is simple:

```
// ================================================
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        AddNewPoint();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        RemoveLastPoint();
    }
}

// ================================================
public void AddNewPoint()
{
    Debug.Log("Add at " + spline.NodeCount);
    spline.AddNode(spline.NodeCount);
}

// ================================================
public void RemoveLastPoint()
{
    spline.RemoveLast();
    Debug.Log("Removed, size is " + spline.NodeCount);
}
```

I also checked that the same problem happens when I add/remove nodes by Playground Spline component in Editor. But as I see there's no such problem when I make a long delay (about 5-10 seconds) between two additions or removals.

Does anyone knows what happens? Also, screenshots:

1. initial state, particles move http://take.ms/xUWBPH
2. after several nodes added particles die http://take.ms/Y7a16